# calculating the volume using cylinderical coordinates.

Tags: integration

I have an example in my assignment which says that:

> The cylinderical coordinates are just polar coordinates on $(x,y)$ -plane and the $z-$ coordinate.
>     $$\phi(r,\theta,z)=(rcos\theta,rsin\theta,z)$$.To get one-one mapping we must have $r\gt 0$ and restrict $\theta$ to $(0,2\pi]$ .Also det$J_\phi(r,\theta,z)=r.$
>   Thus if $S=\phi(U),then$
>   $\int_U f(x,y,z)dx~dy~dz=\int_Sf(\phi(r,\theta,z))~r~dr~d\theta ~dz$.
>
> Find the volume of region $U$ bounded by surfaces $(\frac{x^2+y^2}{a^2})^2+\frac{z}{b}=1$ ,$z=0$ where $a,b\gt 0$ .
>
> **solution** :$\gamma(U)=\int_u1$ .Changing to cylindrical coordinates :
>                      $$\gamma(U)=\int_{\phi(U)}r~dr~d\theta~ dz=\int_0^a \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{b(1-(r/a)^4)}dz~dr~d\theta=\frac {2}{3} \pi a^2b.$$

I can't understand where did $r$ disappear and how did we jump to $\int_0^a\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{b(1-(r/a)^4)}dz~dr~d\theta$ after $\int_{\phi(U)}r~dr~d\theta~ dz$

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: @Jonas $\phi$ is :$\phi(r,\theta,z)=(r cos\theta ,r sin\theta ,z)$

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please provide the reference, book and page number?

Comment: @Jonas these were given as assignment solution by my teacher..well I edit the question exactly as given in assignment... to be more precise

Comment: Thank you.  Did you ask your teacher?

Comment: @Jonas could not as this was last assignment before exam and wasn't discussed by him..

Comment: @JonasMeyer I've edited the question exactly as given in my assignment .Please if you can clear my doubt as I've my exam day after tommorow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing $r$ is a mistake, probably a typo, but the final answer is correct.  The integral is also not written clearly in terms of the order of variables; I accept that there are different conventions, but here there is no consistency, so I suspect that is another typo.  It should be

$$\int_0^a \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{b(1-(r/a)^4)}r\,dz\,d\theta\,dr.$$

or

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a\int_0^{b(1-(r/a)^4)}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta.$$

The equation $\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{a^2}\right)^2+\frac{z}{b}=1$ becomes $\left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^4+\frac{z}{b}=1$.  There is no dependence on $\theta$ in either of the bounding surfaces, which explains the limits of integration for $\theta$.  Rearranging the equation to $z=b(1-(r/a)^4)$ shows where the limits on $r$ and $z$ come from.  For each $r$ from $0$ to $a$, $z$ must be between $0$ and $b(1-(r/a)^4)$.